# How to fix Android Studio 1.0.2 copy bug?

Tags: android-studio

Consider this scenario, I created a new project and made sure it compiles and runs.  I now try to use Refactor->Copy or Refactor->Rename or Refactor->Move.  The project starts spewing errors.

It might have something to do with a bug mentions at
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56284

Quoting:

> This bug still affects version 1.0.2.  The OP discovered the details and posted them in his blog, but didn't bother to update this bug report.
>
> The problem is caused by the fact that the following files (relative to the root of the project) contain the absolute path to the project:
>
> $PROJECTNAME.iml
> $MODULENAME/$MODULENAME.iml
> .idea/gradle.xml
> .idea/workspace.xml
>
> Additionally, with the curious exception of the module .iml, the paths in these files have symlinks resolved, which defeats the purpose of using symlinks in project directories.
>
> The priority on this issue is not 'small'.  The presence of absolute paths in these files renders Android Studio completely unusable for collaborative projects.

In the past, I am able to just move around or rename the project folder and I can still open it without problem on AS, that is because it uses relative paths before.

**My question is, how can I fix the project affected by this bug?**